# Отправка сообщения при старте бота на python в aiogram

Tags: python, бот, aiogram

Всем привет. Каки образом можно при старте бота отправить сообщению юзеру? Использую библиотеку aiogram. Мне нужно что бы при перезапуске бота, отправлялось сообщения юзерам которые им уже пользуются. Что-то на подобии "Бот перезапущен, пропишете /start"

Comment: Почему вы в интернете не искали? Наверное, вот это вам поможет https://github.com/aiogram/aiogram/blob/c42b7e4b0d72503ea1b63a64ff9e0159bc4b68ae/examples/echo_bot.py#L21

Comment: @mrEvgenX Это приветствие при вводе команды /shart, /help. Мне нужно что бы при перезапуске бота, отправлялось сообщения юзерам которые им уже пользуются. Что-то на подобии "Бот перезапущен, пропишете /start"

Comment: Ах, речь про сам сервер, который обрабатывает входящие сообщения. В комментарии всплывает столько любопытных подробностей, перенесите их пожалуйста в вопрос!:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если речь идет про сам сервер, который обрабатывает входящие сообщения, то вам поможет аргумент `on_startup` у метода `executor.start_polling`.

```
# ... код вашего бота


async def on_startup(_):
    user_should_be_notified = 123123123123  # Наверное это должны быть вы сами? Как всезнающий админ:)
    await bot.send_message(user_should_be_notified, 'Бот запущен')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True, on_startup=on_startup)
```

Еще, вдруг, как вариант, метод `executor.start`:

```
# ... код вашего бота


async def on_startup():
    user_should_be_notified = 123123123123
    await bot.send_message(user_should_be_notified, 'Бот запущен')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    executor.start(dp, on_startup())
    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)
```

Если, как всплыло в комментариях, надо отправлять уведомление всем юзерам, которые ботом пользовались, то единственный вариант, насколько я хорошо знаю - запоминать айдишники всех пользователей при первом обращении... Куда-нибудь, где они не потеряются после перезапуска. Потом в цикле по этому сохраненному массиву айдишников вызвать `bot.send_message`.

А еще, если пользователей будет много, то стоит выставить задержку между итерациями, чтобы отправлялось не более 20 сообщений в секунду. Как в [broadcast_example](https://github.com/aiogram/aiogram/blob/c42b7e4b0d72503ea1b63a64ff9e0159bc4b68ae/examples/broadcast_example.py).

Comment: Спасибо большое, работает. Единственное что я не понимаю, метод вроде называется "start", но при запуске, в консоли у меня выводится 'Goodbye!')